# Can't delete file for MemoryMappedFile

Tags: c#, file, memory-mapped-files

The following code throws this exception:

"The process cannot access the file '\filename' because it is being used by another process."

Fair enough, but what's the proper way to close the reader and/or mmf so that the file can be deleted? I would think that MemoryMappedFile would have a close() method or something similar, but it doesn't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(filename,
      System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
      "myMap" + fileNo.ToString(),
      fileSize);

reader = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(0, accessorSize);

<do stuff>

File.Delete(filename);
```

EDITS:

It looks like it's only in the destructor that I'm having this problem. When dispose() is called elsewhere it works fine, but when I do the following it throws the exception. Reader and mmf are obviously members of the class. Is something implicit happening to the file access once the constructor is entered?

```
~Class()
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            reader.Dispose();
            mmf.Dispose();
            File.Delete(filename);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't try to dispose (or access) other objects in a finalizer, since that object might have already been GCed.

Comment: But isn't the point of a destructor to be able to clean up objects before they go out of scope? It think it's moot, though, as I'm having this problem elsewhere in the code too. It's not a destructor-only issue.

Comment: The point of a finalizer is to cleanup unmanaged resources ; reader and mmf ARE managed objects.

Comment: Indeed, the finalizer (.net doesn't have destructors) is a separate issue, I just thought I'd point it. And I do wish MS hadn't used the C++ destructor syntax for finalizers in C#, would probably prevent some of these mistakes with people thinking of it like a C++ destructor.

Answer (score 4):

You should utilize the `using` construct if possible:

```
using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(filename,
                   System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                   "myMap" + fileNo.ToString(), fileSize))
{
    using (reader = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(0, accessorSize))
    {  
       ... <do stuff> ...
    }
}

File.Delete(filename);
```

Otherwise call `Dispose()` on the `reader` and `mmf` objects, however `using` will make sure that it is cleaned up in case exceptions are being thrown in `<do stuff>`.

Answer (score 3):

Prior to deleting the file, you must dispose of the mapping:

```
reader.Dispose();
mmf.Dispose();
File.Delete(filename);
```

Comment: Thanks. So I think that I'm confusing the issue. I had actually tried the above and it didn't work, but after moving stuff around I find out that it only doesn't work in the class destructor (i.e. throws the exception). Do you know why it would not work in the destructor but would work elsewhere in the code?

Comment: I take that back. It runs into problems in places other than the destructor.