# How to delete Memory mapped file?

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

I work with memory-mapped files and after I finish my work I want to delete the files from the disk. but I have the UnauthorizedAccessException in File.Delete(fileName); I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481378/cant-delete-file-for-memorymappedfile) that I should use "using", but i work with several files so I have the array of MemoryMappedFileAccessor's.
my code:

```
var mmf_acc_array = new MemoryMappedViewAccessor[numFiles];
var size = 1048576; //1Mb
var mmf = new MemoryMappedFile[numFiles];
for (int i = 0; i < numFiles; i++)
{
mmf[i] = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine("tmp", "tmp" + i.ToString()));
mmf_acc_array[i] = mmf[i].CreateViewAccessor(0, size);
}

do sm work

for (int i = 0; i < numFiles; i++)
{
mmf_acc_array[i].Dispose();
mmf[i].Dispose();
File.Delete(Path.Combine("tmp", "tmp" + i.ToString()));
}
```

Exception arises in File.Delete(); How can I free the file?

Comment: What message is contained in the exception?

Comment: Access denied to path "tmp//tmp0"

Comment: I don't see the problem.  The code is strange but you normally create mmfs to share with another process.  Is it still running?

Comment: yes. file is busy after mmf[i].Dispose();